# React updating array of objects in state

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

I am having some trouble with my react application.

I am trying to dynamically update an array of objects inside of an object which is stored in state.

When the user presses a button, it creates a new object in state with a UUID, this parent object hold an array of objects for the content. by default when creating the parent object it adds a single content object to the array inside the parent object.

I need to now be able to add more objects inside of that child array.

the problem I have is then once i create the parent object (which works well,) I try to add one of the content objects but it causes the whole component to re-render and my parent objects to disappear. However once they have diapered I can no longer create a parent object as it says 'Uncaught TypeError: scratchTickers.push is not a function'

so basically I create one object which creates say a list, the content array inside of the list object should populate the list with items.

Ticker is the parent object,

`_createTicker` creates a blank object with UUID and a single item object in the 'content array'. I can call this multiple times and it works as it should.

The problem arrises when i call `_createTickerItem` this should pull in the correct ticker object by looping through them all and finding the matching ID, then it pulls the content array and saves it to a local variable, pushes a new blank content object to this array and should then update the state.

Doing this causes the whole component to re-render, when this happens I can no longer create the ticker objects as I get the error `'Uncaught TypeError: scratchTickers.push is not a function'`

here is the code I have:

```
getInitialState () {
        return {
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getMuiTheme(themeSwitcher.getMaterialTheme()),
            scratchTickers: [],
        };
    },

    _createTicker: function() {
        var blankTicker = {
            id       : uuid.v1(),
            area     : 'Scratch',
            name     : 'Untitled',
            status   : "",
            size     : "",
            created  : {
                name : "username",
                time : new Date()
            },
            modified : {
                name : "username",
                time : new Date()
            },
            content: [{
                content: "Dummy content",
                TowerRed: "",
                TowerText: "Headlines"
            }]
        };

        let scratchTickers = this.state.scratchTickers;

        scratchTickers.push(blankTicker);

        this.setState({scratchTickers: scratchTickers});
    },

    _createTickerItem: function (id) {
        console.log("creating ticker item");
        console.log("Ticker ID: ", id);
        var tickerID = id;
        var key      = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.scratchTickers.length; i++) {

            if(this.state.scratchTickers[i].id == tickerID) {
                var ticker = this.state.scratchTickers[i];
                var key    = i;
            }
        }

        var blankContent = ({
                content: "Ticker Content",
                TowerRed: "",
                TowerText: "Headlines"
            });

        var currentContent = this.state.scratchTickers[key].content;

        var newContent = [];

        currentContent.push(blankContent);

        this.setState({
            scratchTickers: update(this.state.scratchTickers[key], {content: {$set: currentContent}})
        });


    },
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately!

Comment: how should it be formatted? I cant see an issue with it.

Comment: It is badly indented; hence long lines that are wrapped and unreadable on mobile, so it's not a big issue, just some spaces to remove :)

Comment: ahh, Ok, i shall update it later. Thanks.

Comment: You are mutating the state directly. `let scratchTickers = this.state.scratchTickers;` does not create a copy of the array. Use the react update helper to do any push operations.